# Evaluate $\int_{}^{}e^{(\sin^{-1} x)}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral :

$\int_{}^{}e^{(\sin^{-1} x)}dx$

I started solving this problem with Integration By Parts technique, setting $dv=dx$ and $u=e^{(\sin^{-1} x)}$

But I got an integral more complicated in the next step

Can this integral be solved by this technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $x=sin(u)$

$dx=\cos(u) du$
by using by part to get
$$\int e^u \cos u du=e^u\sin u+e^u\cos u-\int e^u\cos u du+C$$
$$2\int e^u \cos u du=e^u\sin u+e^u\cos u+C
$$

$$\int e^u(\cos u)\ du=\frac{1}{2}e^{u} (\sin u+\cos u)+C_1$$
$$\int e^u(\cos u)\ du=\frac{1}{2}e^{u} (\sin u+\sqrt{1-\sin u^2})+C_1$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{sin^{-1} x} (x+\sqrt{1-x^2})+C_1$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x= \sin\theta$. Can you solve it now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=sin(\theta)$. Then $dx=\cos(\theta) d\theta$.
Then the integral is
$$I=\int e^{\theta}cos(\theta)d\theta$$
Let $u=e^{\theta}$, $dv=\cos(\theta)$, so 
$$I=e^{\theta}\sin(\theta)-\int e^{\theta}\sin(\theta)d\theta$$
Then $u=e^{\theta}$, $dv=\sin(\theta)$,
$$I=e^{\theta}\sin(\theta)+e^{\theta}\cos(\theta)-I$$
So then
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\theta}\sin(\theta)+e^{\theta}\cos(\theta)\right)+C$$
Simply plug back in the original substitution and use the Pythagorean identity for $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: You have a typo in the penultimate formula, it must be $\dotsc - I$ on the right hand side.